# Controlling spotwelder timer with 555

Tags: circuit-analysis, 555, timing

I want to use the 555 time to control the timing on the power pulse of a spot-welder using a foot switch.

I have seen a few 555 mono-stable circuits, but am having trouble finding the values of the resistors and capacitors in order to get times below 1 second.

Also, I want to connect this circuit to a spot welder in a safe way, because of power difference. My spot welder is made of a MOT, and have a pedal switch to do the switching.

How should I connect these parts together? What kind of pot/cap combo for sub 1 second timing with a 555 timer?

[image]

I wanted to add the image at the bottom of the page, but didn't know how.
So, i have to put over here.
Please let me know any modifications that i should do with the connections.
Also, i would like to add a POT in the 555 timer circuit in order to adjust the timing. Where should i put it?
Thank you for any help...[image]

Comment: As you correctly observed, the timer circuit is just a small part of your problems. You need something to switch large currents. That's where relays come in. There's timer relays. As usual, when someone tries to actually build something useful from the 555: for most its applications that ic has long be superseded with cleverer contraptions.

Comment: And the fact that you know neither how to design that 555 circuit nor what kind of switch you might want nor how to wire these up: I'm afraid the by far shortest possible answer to your question would be to build that whole thing for you; an indication that your question is *too broad*.

Comment: One option is to buy "relay timers". They are 6 to 8 pin and plug into a socket with screw terminals. The timer is built in and adjustable.

Comment: 555s have datasheets. Datasheets contain example circuits and formulas for calculating resistor and capacitor values. All that is easy compared with the rest of the welder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.
I didn't know that there's timer relays, i will look into it.

I have an ssr 80amps to isolate the 555 circuit.

The problem i have is connecting properly the timer circuit to the ssr and spotwelder and the foot switch to the timer circuit... also trying to adjust the timing to control the amount of power (which is fixed) send to the welding spot. Because i will be spot welding different thickness i would like to be able to adjust the amount of power controlling the timing in miliseconds.  Thank you very much for your comments

Answer (score 2):

[image: 555 MonStable]

MonoStable with switch

Sorry fella, I should read it a bit clearer.  I had it in my mind with the last post it was a MIG type thing with pulsed outputs...Hopefully the above will make it  a bit clearer for you.

Comment: No problem,  i appreciate your input . Because i would like to dynamically change the timing,  which resistor should i change with a potentiometer. Do any pot will do? Or it is a specific kind of pot that I should used?

Comment: If you had say 20uF cap for C1 then a 100K pot for R1 this would give you a theoretical range of around 0 to 2.2 seconds.. No special requirements for the type of pot..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. .... will be possible to let me know if my connection and wiring are correct in my crude drawing ? Just want to make sure, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[image]

something like 82Uf for C R1= 10 K and R2 maybe a 0 to 25 k pot with a 5k in series would get what you asked for. But you may want to alter the mark space ration rather than just the on period so maybe 1 second on and five seconds off.  Has the spot welder already got a small switch on the handle or something ? If so then it may already have the facility to use a low voltage switch to trigger the large current welding supply. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the sketch and the cap/resistor values.  I will try them.

Comment: Would that be an answer then ? or maybe a point ?

Comment: Yes, partially. It's good to have those values, good start point.

Comment: Yes, partially. It's good to have those values, good start point. Having an sketch is a lot easier for me to understand. Would you please tell me based in ur sketch how/where i connect the relay with the spotwelder and the food pedal switch in order to trigger the timer. I appreciate very much your time and help. Thank you

Comment: I can't really answer that unless I knew the lay out of yoru particular system.

Comment: You may have a switch on the welder that puts the current on and off. Hopefully it will be a low power/voltage switch that operates some relay or electronics in the welder to actually apply the current. IF this is the case then you would need to put a small relay in parallel to this switch. One way would then be for a clean contact on the foot switch to apply the supply voltage to the circuit above and the output of the circuit used to drive the new parallel relay.

Comment: Remember I'm only throwing ideas at you for you to think about I'm not telling you how you should do it. I really hope you wont take this the wrong way but if you have to ask how to include a circuit like the one above in to a system to make it work, are you confident enough to tackle a project like this ?

Comment: Hello. .. did u have a chance to look at the sketch i uploaded?   I really would like to see your advice. . Thanks

Comment: The switch would have to go in between the output and the SSR. Not ideal as you would get a pulse train rather than a one shot idea but it would work..

Comment: Thanks for getting back. ..
I would loose the time control if i do that. The whole idea of the timer was to control the time of the electric pulse. 

I don't want to rely in my foot reflect to control the time.
I might be interpreting wrong your suggestion though, will be possible you can redraw my sketch to show your idea please. 
Thanks again for your comments, i really do appreciate it. 
Good day

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pull down pins 2 and 6 with the switch you want to do it as I have shown in the diagram above. Also the output will go high (ie + WRT 0V) so your SSR would have to be around the other way but still tied to pin 3. You'd have to check with the data sheet of the SSR to see if it is happy to be connected directly (Volts and current wise) to the output of the 555.  If you already have these components then the 555 stuff is so cheap you can set it up on a breadboard utilising maybe 12v and make sure everything is doing what you want before going anywhere near the lethal stuff. 
Remember these are only hypothetical ideas you take full responsibility for your own actions..

Comment: Hello... and thanks again for your comments. I uploaded a revision of the drawing (are my connection OK?). I don't understand by putting the SSR around the other way, could you clarify that please. Will be great if can draw any changes and suggestions, that way I don't have to guess. if is not too much trouble of course. Thank you.

Comment: If you look at the diagram below you will see that the output of the 555 sits at 0v then pulses to near the supply voltage for the duration of the pulse then returns to 0v again. The way you have it connected to the SSR is the SSR would be on all the time the output of the 555 was at 0V thus all the time the pedal isn't pressed. The output of the 555 needs to go to the + of the SSR. As said in my last post check the fan out of the 555 is higher than the fan in of the SSR. IE make sure the 555 can supply enough current to turn on the SSR. Other than that your diagram looks ok.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the clarification. ... many years ago i took basic clases of electronics,  i enjoy fixing and doing projects. Many times i get into trouble figuring out how a circuit works cause i learned that current flow from negative to positive. In the 555 timer circuit,  i assume that output 3 in negative. Anyway , i really appreciate your help.  Once i put it all together will let you know how it went. Thanks

Comment: Today i was testing the circuitry. It works,  with one inconvenience.  When i try to fire up repeatedly,  it doesn't work, i think it needs a few seconds to recharge the capacitor,  if i wait a few seconds like 4 or 5 seconds,  it does work ok. Is there a way to modify the circuit  in order to make it fire up repeatedly with less than a second between firing? Hope there is!! Thanks

Comment: Well ok you could multi fire it but it wouldn't then fit your original request. If you want a one second (or whatever) pulse no matter how many times or how long the foot pedal is pressed then the above circuit will do it. In your rapid pedal pressing idea what do you want to happen if you press the pedal multi times during the on period ?

Comment: Some thoughts. You could use the pedal to discharge the capacitor C1. C1 has to be at near zero volts to rearm the timer circuit. However, this would mean keep your foot down and it never times out. Take your foot off in the time period and it should start the time from the foot lift. Press the pedal again during a pulse and the timer would start timing again. So basically, your time period is set to the 1 second from the time the pedal is lifted.

Comment: A simple way of doing this (which I’m not sure will work the way you want but if you have it bread boarded it would be easy enough to try) Disconnect pin 7 take out R2 then connect Pin 6 to pin 2 and to the foot switch so that the foot switch drags  Pin 2 and 6 to 0V when the pedal is pressed (leaving R1 and C1 connected to pin 6 as before)

Comment: Well, when i spotweld batteries,  i prefer to have twice welded( not in the same place) on each battery,  jut to make it more secure. The pulse i wanted to last like 500 mili seconds or half of a second,  then i move the battery  a little bit to have a 2nd weld, this goes very fast. It takes me less than a second to fire up for the 2nd time. That's how it goes. Hope there is a way to do this. Thank you

Comment: Just remenber please, i am using the 2nd  555 timer circuit  (the one with the colors) so pin 7 is not connected to R2....

Comment: That's right pin 7 isn't connected to R2 but if you try the modification above Pin 7 isn't connected to anything.. Give it a go on your breadboard see if it is what you want.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try. So pin 7 will be floting! , it won't be a problem?

Comment: Pin 7 goes to the collector of a transistor inside the chip with the emitter connected to 0V so it won't matter if it is floating. Tie it to 0v if you feel the need to do something with it.

Comment: Well, so far so good. Testing it in the breadboard works as it should with the changes suggested.Because the 555 can only handle miliamps, would be ok to trigger the ssr?. I'm using 12vdc to power the timer circuit at 1.5 amps. I just wondering a continuous use will burn the 555.

Comment: An afterthought,  where should i put a red LED in order to indicate the circuit been powered?

Comment: You are not powering the SSR with the 555 just triggering it. Check the data sheet to see what the trigger current is the 555 sticks out about 200ma maximum if I remember correctly.  If it manages to do say 20 in a row in quick succession then it will probably be ok when used intermittently. Put the 555 in a chip socket rather than solder it in then you can swap it easier. LED for output on or for circuit energised ?

Comment: Circuit energised.

Comment: Circuit energised, for the led....... you are right, it is around 200mA. And im using a socket for the 555, just in case. Now, i just need to put it all together. Im looking in the internet for a probes design that i can make to easily lower the probes to make the weld. I knowwthere are many around, i have looked around, but i haven't found one that will free my hands, specially one i  can make. Thanks for your help , i can't say it enough

Comment: For circuit energised. You have a + and - coming out of your power supply at 12VDC  put a 1k resister and an LED across those terminals and the LED will come on (if it is the right way around) as soon as you switch the power supply on.   Maybe you could mark this as an answered question if you are happy with it.

Comment: Yes, i believe it has been answered. I was looking around in how i do that, but can't see how i could mark it as answered. Thanks very much  to everyone

Comment: click on the up arrow next to the answers for each answer you found useful. I got a -1 from a Dave Tweed , not really sure why...